# Why is DRF (Distributed Random Forest) slower than XGBoost in h2o automl

Tags: xgboost, h2o, automl, h2o.ai

I am using H2O Auto ML and while comparing the time for XGBoost and D-RandomForest, DRF is taking a lot more time than XGBoost!

Code for DRF:

```
x = hf.columns
y = target_metric
x.remove(y)
aml = H2OAutoML(max_models=1, seed=1, include_algos=["DRF"])
aml.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=hf)
m = aml.leader
varimp = m.varimp(use_pandas=True)
```

Code for XGboost:

```
x = hf.columns
y = target_metric
x.remove(y)
aml = H2OAutoML(max_models=1, seed=1, include_algos=["XGBoost"])
aml.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=hf)
m = aml.leader
varimp = m.varimp(use_pandas=True)
```

[H2O-AUTOML](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html)